# Sorting a vector within a vector pair

Tags: c++, debugging, stl

Consider this snippet in C++

```
vector<pair<int, vector<long long int>>> strengthVector;

// sorting
for (auto x : strengthVector) {
  sort(x.second.begin() + 1, x.second.end(), greater<long long int>());
}

// calculate prefix sum
for (auto x : strengthVector) {
  for (j = 1; j < x.second.size(); j++) {
    x.second[j] += x.second[j - 1];
  }
}
```

I want to sort the vector with each pair. I've tried it doing following way. But when i'm printing the values for debugging purpose, it shows me that none of the above two operations happened.

While debugging the code in vscode, i'm getting following error `__for_begin: <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>{_M_current = 0x7fffffffda90}` .

I don't know what it means. Kindly enlighten.

Comment: By the way, there is an existing function for calculating your prefix sums: [std::inclusive_scan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inclusive_scan)

Comment: @honk this is excatly what i was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop

```
for (auto x : strengthVector)
```

makes a *copy* of every element in `strengthVector` so you're not actually modifying it.

You need to iterate by reference

```
for (auto &x : strengthVector)
```